# Selenium grid Kubernetes Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, grid

We have selenium hub deployed on kubernetes cliuster on AWS and used ingress-traefik to expose service.
We have also have selenium chrome node registered to this selenium hub on kubernetes.

When i see the grid console page i can see the chrome node attached to this hub.
[image]

But when i trigger my automation suite through Jenkins i am getting the below error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.165-103.209.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at stepDefns.SetUp.setUpBrowser(SetUp.java:145)
    at stepDefns.OrderSpecTabSteps.user_sets_the_browser_to_and_version(OrderSpecTabSteps.java:25)
    at ✽.Given user sets the browser to "chrome" and version "69"(/data/jenkins_home/workspace/FPSAutomation/src/test/java/features/NonRes.feature:4)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
```

in Logs i can see **Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out**

In My java code I am using node url as below which is **"HTTPS"**

```
String nodeURL = "https://<hostname>/wd/hub";
ChromeOptions remoteOptions = new ChromeOptions();

driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), remoteOptions);
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in Advance.